# Validate JSON against a schema in .NET

Tags: .net, json, validation, jsonschema

I know there is a proposed standard for JSON schema validation, is there an implementation in .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/01/04/json-net-3-5-beta-2-json-schema-validation.aspx) has this functionality.

Comment: JSON Schema validation has been moved to its own package. See http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema

Comment: And it's not free

Comment: It is, there's a free (albeit somewhat limited - 1k validations/hr) version under the AGPL.

Answer (score 17):

A free and open-source alternative to Json.NET is [NJsonSchema](http://njsonschema.org) (JSON Schema draft 4).

Answer (score 2):

- [Json Everything](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything) and its predecesor [Manatee.Json](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Json) are quite good and fast.
- [NJsonSchema](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema) comfortable api however too slow for our use case (schema closing to 100kb the json in 10s of kbs); the above mentioned Manatee and json-everything have a "flag-only" validation mode which is missing here
- [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) (Paid)
  i have not checked this one

Answer (score 0):

Add Newtonsoft's Json NuGet Package in your solution. Add below function and pass Schema and your json response in string to below function.

```
  public void ValidateSchema(JsonSchema JSchema, string JsonString)  {
        JsonString = JsonString.Replace("\"", "'");
        var ArrJobj = JArray.Parse(JsonString);

        foreach (JObject jo in ArrJobj)
        {
            if (!jo.IsValid(JSchema)) throw new Exception("Schems Validation failed");

        }

    }
```

Hope this helps